# SIGSEGV accessing structure member in C

Tags: c, variable-assignment, segmentation-fault

I have something like this in C:

```
unsigned char a = structTypeInstance->b ;
```

where `b` has the same type as `a`.

Upon this I receive `SIGSEGV`.

Why?

**Edit:** I can access previous declared fields of structTypeInstance. My only hunch is that where memory is allocated for structTypeInstance, it is not enough. Is that possible?

Comment: You mean `SIGSEGV`, "Invalid memory reference", right? Show how you declare the structure type and how you define and initialize a variable of that type.

Comment: StructType is a pointer to a complex structure .

Comment: I can access another member of the structure, but not this one.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov  you gave me a clue. As I said, I can access some fields that are declared before the one that generates seg fault. Maybe It has allocated to phew memory. You think it is possible ?

Comment: What does `printf ("%p\n", (void*) StructType);` print? How was it allocated and how was the memory it points to filled?

Comment: With this amount of information - yes, everything is possible :)

Comment: @Jens I do not know how it is allocated. I'm investigating right now. As for haw it is filled, what does that matter? Even if nothing is assigned to that unsigned char value, it should not give a SIGSEGV.

Comment: SIGSEGV means you tried to dereference a pointer with an address that is outside of your allocated memory space. This most often happens with the pointer is null, but it could also be the case that when malloc (or something similar) was used to allocate memory for the struct it did not grab enough bytes. And the offset for "b" is outside of the memory space.

Comment: @desimusxvii That is my hunch also, but from what i found( and I'm not sure since it is a very complex code), there is enough memory allocated) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is possible. But since you refuse to show us the code where `structTypeInstance` is declared, what the definition of the corresponding struct is in its entirety, where it is assigned to, we can't really be sure.

Sometimes the bug is as simple as writing

```
struct FOOBAR {
   char big[16380];
   char b[4];
};
struct FOOBAR *foo;

foo = malloc (sizeof foo); /* Allocates just a handful of bytes. */
```

when you really meant

```
foo = malloc (sizeof *foo); /* Allocates enough for a complete struct FOOBAR. */
```

Comment: Is proprietary code and i cannot show it.

Comment: Please replace identifiers and strip it down so we can't tell {BIG COMPANY} writes shoddy code.

Comment: It's not about you telling which, it's about them not to :) .

Comment: Well, from what I see for the moment it allocates less memory than it should. I think this is because of numerous define directives.